# Having images prepended using an array and for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple thumbnails I am trying to loop through and add to a site in an efficient way. Unfortunately I cannot seem to get them to appear the way I have set-up.

It's suppose to loop through strings in an array and add those strings to *img src's* markup, which will then be appended to the HTML; "reggie" is called by an earlier function and it does fire (I tested it with an alert).

The images are "editorial-cheese" and "editorial-lego", both in an "images/folder".

```
var images = ["cheese", "lego"];

function reggie() {

    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {

        $('.port2').prepend("<img class='cheese hover' 
        src='images/editorial-"+i+".png'/>");

        i++;

    }
}
```

Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks.

Comment: What is content of $('.port2') after function execution? did you get anything in html? Try to use inspect feature in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are looping through, and printing out the number you are currently on (0, then 1). You need to get the image from your array instead. Also, as a note, you don't need the second increment at the bottom of your loop; your for-loop is handling it.

Here is it rewritten:

```
var images = ["cheese", "lego"];
function reggie() {
    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {

        $('.port2').prepend("<img class='cheese hover' 
        src='images/editorial-" + images[i] + ".png'/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: %^&# me, that was a fast and working response! Thanks a bunch! (I wish there was a "newbie" tag, though, so I wouldn't bother people uninterested in newbie questions.)

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, done. I'm curious: if I have multiple small follow-up questions not completely related to this, should I ask them here or create new posts?

Comment: Create a new post. You'll get a much better response that way (others will be able to see it)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to increment i inside the for loop, remove i++